# Which version of java is required for Struts 1.3.10

Tags: java, struts

Which version of java is required for Struts 1.3.10

I am planning to upgrade the struts version from 1.2.9 to 1.3.10. Please let me know which version of java is required for this upgrade? I am currently using java 1.4

Comment: You really call this an upgrade? Why are you still stuck with Struts 1.x?

Comment: Why bother? Unless you have a specific need for the functionality in S1.3, which you almost certainly don't, leave it as-is. If you're going to do anything, re-write to a modern framework like Struts 2, Spring MVC, etc. or go all-out and move to Grails, Rails, Play, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [installation guide](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/userGuide/installation.html) for `1.3.x`:

> Java Development Kit - You must download and install a Java
>   Development Kit (**version 1.4 or later**) implementation for your
>   operating system platform.